# Bentley DGN format to Oracle Spatial

Tags: oracle-spatial, dgn

Did anyone ingested the DGN (all versions) to Oracle Spatial?

Comment: We do every day using FME http://www.safe.com/fme/fme-technology/fme-desktop/overview/

Answer (score 2):

@Rao, ogr2ogr can do this (at least, the [OGR formats page](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/index.html) shows both [Microstation DGN](https://gdal.org/ogr/drv_dgn.html) as well as [Oracle Spatial](https://gdal.org/ogr/drv_oci.html)); however, you'll need a GDAL/OGR installation that includes support for Oracle. If you're using Windows, you should find everything you need [on Tamas Szekeres site](https://www.gisinternals.com/sdk.php), otherwise check [here](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadingGdalBinaries) and look for an OS-specific approach to installing GDAL.

Presumably, your ogr2ogr instruction should look something like this (based on a quick look at the documentation):

`ogr2ogr -nlt "geometry" -f OCI OCI:username/password@database samp4.dgn`

Although, both the DGN and the Oracle formats have a number of particulars, so you may want to consider translating your DGN files to shapefiles first, then translating the shapefiles into Oracle. I only suggest this because using shapefiles in the middle would allow you to isolate any DGN or Oracle-specific driver-complexities to one side of the equation at a time.

Take a look at this [conversation between Loskot and Warmerdam](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2005-October/006946.html) for some additional insight.